# Parsing a URL for its img links in python

Tags: python, html, parsing

I am trying to parse a URL to get all of its image links by using the img tags. I can get the tuple with the `src` and `url` but cannot figure out how to work with the tuple and only print the `url`. Please help

```py
class ImageLinks(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag in 'img':
            print(attrs[0])

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag in 'img':
            print()
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to *unpack these tuples* into attribute name and value variables:

```
def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    if tag == 'img':
        for attr_name, attr_value in attrs:
            if attr_name == "src":
                print(attr_value)
                break  # early exit as we've found our attribute
```

Or, you could *create a dictionary* out of all attributes and get the one by attribute name:

```
if tag == 'img':
    attributes = dict(attrs)
    print(attributes.get("src"))
```

---

All that said, you may find third-party libraries like [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/index.html) more intuitive, better documented and generally much more powerful, check them out.

Answer (score 0):

Your string matching must be the other way around.

```
class ImageLinks(HTMLParser):
def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)

def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if 'img' in tag:
          for attr in attrs:
            if(attr[0] == 'src'):
              print(att[1])

def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if 'img' in tag:
             print()
```